# MoSync Update LocalFiles without prompting

Tags: jquery, mobile-application, local-files, mosync

I have a mobile App developed in MoSync. It uses jQuery Mobile, and its all very beautiful. My Business Manager asks (A typical business manager question probably): **How can we update the app without prompting the user?**

I don't think we can update the CPP base files, and I certainly don't think we can change the app's permissions without prompting the user. But the LocalFiles folder only contains HTML5 and JS, this should be perfectly possible to update on the mobilephone, without prompting the user.

But how? Does the compiler compile this LocalFiles folder to some binary, that we can download from the phone and replace the old related file? Zip all the files in the LocalFiles folder, and let the app download and extract them to replace the ones on the mobile? Or is there some complicated packaging of the LocalFiles folder going on at the compilation level that we don't quite see?

Of course, things will get more complicated cross-platform wise, but for now I want to know the answer for Android.

A nice answer would be a link to an example app.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see, Mosync doesn't currently support zip because of potential memory issues on platforms other than IOS/Android.

Mosync Reload has been currently released though, which does exactly what you want.
It uses a custom build process to package your files into some custom type of archive, which it can extract on the device.